# How can I fix this Ember CLI error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, ember-cli, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm integrating my first `Ember` application in a Rails project. I have added the `ember-cli-rails` gem and ran the initializer so that I have a `config/initializers/ember.rb` file that looks like this:

```
EmberCLI.configure do |c|
  c.app :products, path: 'products'
end
```

My Ember application is in my Rails app root and is called `products`. I have done nothing other than generate a default Ember application for now.

I have created a specific layout for `ProductsController` in Rails. It's `app/views/products.html.erb`. I have added the following lines:

```
<%= include_ember_script_tags :products %>
<%= include_ember_stylesheet_tags :products %>
```

I have also edited the `router.js` file for the Ember application since I am not serving up the Ember app at the root URL:

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  rootURL:  config.baseURL, // added this line
  location: config.locationType
});
```

Finally I changed `config/environments.js` in my Ember app

```
var ENV = {
  modulePrefix: 'products',
  environment: environment,
  baseURL: '/products', // changed from '/' to '/products'
  locationType: 'auto',
  EmberENV: {
    FEATURES: {
      // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
      // e.g. 'with-controller': true
    }
  },
```

The index page comes up fine for this controller. And it's trying to load the Ember files, but I am receiving an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: rootURL must end with a trailing forward slash e.g. "/app/"
```

The instructions for `ember-cli-rails` don't include a trailing slash.

And if I do add the trailing slash, I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Path /products does not start with the provided rootURL /products/
```

I realize I'm probably missing something very basic in my first Ember application here. Thank you very sincerely for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails/issues/111)

So go ahead and add the trailing slash to the `baseURL`. Then follow the instructions in the post linked above, which I will summarize here:

```
class YourEmberAppController

  before_action :ensure_trailing_slash

  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    render :index
  end

  def vehicles
  end

  def save
  end

  private

  def ensure_trailing_slash
    unless trailing_slash?
      redirect_to url_for(params.merge(trailing_slash: true)), status: 301
    end
  end

  def trailing_slash?
    request.env['REQUEST_URI'].match(/[^\?]+/).to_s.last == '/'
  end

end
```

Do this and you will be greeted with "Welcome to Ember" as part of your page.

Comment: I have also since learned that this is an old-fashioned way of including an Ember application inside of a Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails' `routes.rb`:

```
get 'products', to: redirect('/products/'), constraints: lambda { |req| req.env['REQUEST_URI'].last != '/' }
```